# Let $a,b$ be affine combinations of points from a set $S$. Then is the affine combination of $a,b$ also an affine combination of points from $S$?

Tags: affine-geometry

> Let A be an affine space, $a,b$ affine combinations of points from a finite subset $S$ of A. Then is the affine combination of $a,b$ also an affine combination of points from $S$?

I found it hard to show because it involves two affine combinations and things get quite complicatd.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=c_i s^i$ and $b=d_i s^i$ (both sums) then $\lambda a +\mu b=(\lambda c_i+\mu d_i)s^i$.

Comment: Why is $(\lambda c_i+\mu d_i)$ equal to 1? why is affine combination associative and distributive?

Comment: Your affine space is presumably over a field such as the real numbers, so the associative and distributive laws are assumed.